# Using bootstrap why do these label and input controls not show up on the same line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Why would the label and Field (just a wrapper for input) not display on the same line?

I believe that I'm following the simple instructions found here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_medium.asp

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="row">
        <label htmlFor="something" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Somethingwefwef</label>
        <Field className="col-sm-10" name="something" type="text" component="input" className="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your whole mark-up is problematic. Try to follow the tutorial carefully.

**You should do it like this**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
            <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <label For="something" class="col-sm-2 form-label">Somethingwefwef</label>
        <input class="col-sm-10" name="something" type="text"  class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. My code is jsx and still has an issue, but you have helped me get closer. This snippet is inside of a few more div tags with class names specified. Unfortunately, the input box is covering part of the label now, but they are on the same row.

Comment: Ok, I've realized my issue. Somebody disabled the container bootstrap class as a hack by defining it again inside a local stylesheet that is pulled in by the web app. UGH!!!